# How to build polygons from buffered points and merge overlapping ones using R?

Tags: r, sp, sf, rgeos

I have a sample of 3 groups of points which are similarly spread within their groups.

```
> pts
             x        y
 [1,] 453067.5 364073.5
 [2,] 453066.5 364072.5
 [3,] 453068.5 364072.5
 [4,] 453063.5 364071.5
 [5,] 453065.5 364071.5
 [6,] 453067.5 364071.5
 [7,] 453069.5 364071.5
 [8,] 453071.5 364071.5
 [9,] 453062.5 364070.5
[10,] 453064.5 364070.5
[11,] 453067.5 364065.5
[12,] 453069.5 364065.5
[13,] 453071.5 364065.5
[14,] 453073.5 364065.5
[15,] 453075.5 364065.5
[16,] 453077.5 364065.5
[17,] 453079.5 364065.5
[18,] 453054.5 364064.5
[19,] 453056.5 364064.5
[20,] 453058.5 364064.5
```

Then I can convert to `sp` object: `pts_sf = sf::st_as_sf(as.data.frame(pts), coords = c(1,2))`. Now trying to create buffer `pts_buf <- gBuffer(pts_sf, TRUE, 2)` but get error

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘is.projected’ for signature ‘"sf"’

Other way round, I can use buffer like this `pts_buf <- sf::st_buffer(pts_sf, 2)` but now I get error when trying `pts_uni <- rgeos::gIntersects(pts_buf, byid=TRUE, returnDense = FALSE)`

> Error in RGEOSBinPredFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, func) :
>   rgeos_convert_R2geos: invalid R class, unable to convert

I use `pts_int = sf::st_intersects(pts_buf)` but this is not an object I need. Can I find any compatibilities to go out with it?

Comment: If you found a solution, don't publish it as a part of your question but as an answer to your own question (and remove it from question).

Comment: The reason for your initial failure is because the functions from `sf` create objects that can't be read by functions in the `rgeos` package (like `gBuffer`). `rgeos` uses the earlier `sp` class objects.

Comment: agreed twice guys

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution using `sf` package:

So having a matrix of points, First I need sf object

```
pts_sf = sf::st_as_sf(as.data.frame(pts), coords = c(1,2))
```

Next I can perform buffer

```
pts_buf <- sf::st_buffer(pts_sf, 2)
```

then union

```
pts_com <- sf::st_union(pts_buf)
```

and ath end I can get normal polygon from it

```
pts_pol <- sf::st_cast(pts_com, "POLYGON")
```

This works well for larger data as well. Tested for up to 1M of points.